# Matlab Saving the Output of a Function (preferably as a csv)

Tags: matlab, csv, export-to-csv

I know this kind of thing has been asked before but nothing I have tried has helped.

I've borrowed a function from github for a project but it's in matlab and my project is in python so I want to save the output data as a csv so I can input it back into python.

I've literally only been using matlab for about 4 hrs so this could be a stupid question...

I've tried an array of different methods for saving as a csv but none of them have worked. They don't throw errors though, the files just don't show up.

This is my latest attempt:

```
clear;clc;

fileName = 'AlzScSK.csv';
csvData = importdata(fileName);

rawData = csvData.data;
dataMV = rawData;
scaledMV = dataMV

K = 6;

function [dataImputed dataImputedWeighted] = NSkNNDataHM(dataMV)
% Function to impute missing values in a dataset using NSkNN. scaledMV is 
% the autoscale dataset with the missing values and K is the # of nearest 
% neighbors to use to impute the data. filteredMV is the missing value 
% dataset after filtering, but before autoscaling.
% NSkNNData_HM does not skip neighbors that have NaN values in the same 
% location as the metabolite being imputed. Instead, it replaces these NaN 
% values with the half minimum value of that metabolite.

numCol = size(scaledMV,2);

for col = 1:numCol
    rowMV{col} = find(isnan(scaledMV(:,col))); % Finds the row # of every missing value in each column
end

counter = 1;
for targetCol = 1:numCol % i is the target sample
    for neighborCol = 1:numCol % Calculate the Euclidean distances between the target sample (i) and the other samples (j)
        MVRowsRemoved = scaledMV;
        rowsToRemove = union(rowMV{targetCol},rowMV{neighborCol}); % Ignore NaNs when calculating distances
        MVRowsRemoved(rowsToRemove,:) = []; % Remove rows in target sample that have missing values
        numMetInCalc = size(MVRowsRemoved,1); % # of metabolites used in calculation of metabolites in order to weight distance
        % Divide by numMetInCalc to avoid scenarios where distances 
        % calculated with only a few metabolites are weighted more heavily 
        % over distances that are close to the same distance, but used more 
        % metabolites in the calculation.
        distance = pdist2(MVRowsRemoved(:,targetCol)',MVRowsRemoved(:,neighborCol)')/sqrt(numMetInCalc);  
        %distance = pdist2(MVRowsRemoved(:,targetCol)',MVRowsRemoved(:,neighborCol)');
        distIdx(counter,:) = [targetCol distance neighborCol];
        counter = counter+1;
    end
end

% Remove rows that calculated the Euclidean distance between a sample and
% itself.
sameSample = find(distIdx(:,1)==distIdx(:,3));
distIdx(sameSample,:) = [];
distIdxSorted = sortrows(distIdx);

minValperRow = min(scaledMV,[],2); % Finds minimum of each metabolite

% Implement NSkNN with half minimum replacement
dataImputed = scaledMV;
dataImputedWeighted = scaledMV;
for targetCol = 1:numCol
    numMV = size(rowMV{targetCol},1); % # of missing values in a column
    firstNNIdx = (targetCol-1)*(numCol-1)+1; % Column index of the first nearest neighbor of target sample (i) in distIdxSorted
    for MVidx = 1:numMV % For each missing value in the target sample...
        tempDataMV = scaledMV;
        NN = distIdxSorted(firstNNIdx:firstNNIdx+K-1,3); % Column #s of the k nearest neighbors
        DistanceNN = distIdxSorted(firstNNIdx:firstNNIdx+K-1,2); % Distances of k nearest neighbors
        idxNaNinCol = find(isnan(tempDataMV(rowMV{targetCol}(MVidx),NN))); % Finds missing values that are the same metabolite as the target metabolite to be imputed
        if isempty(idxNaNinCol)~=1 % If NaN values found...
            % If there are NaN values in the nearest neighbor
            % metabolite that is the same as the target metabolite to
            % be imputed, replace with half min value of the target
            % metabolite

            tempDataMV(rowMV{targetCol}(MVidx),NN(idxNaNinCol)) = (minValperRow(rowMV{targetCol}(MVidx)) - avgMV(rowMV{targetCol}(MVidx))/stddevMV(rowMV{targetCol}(MVidx)))/2;           
        end
        % Imputed data is weighted by the inverse of the distance
        WeightMultiplier = (1./DistanceNN')/sum(1./DistanceNN);
        dataImputedWeighted(rowMV{targetCol}(MVidx),targetCol) = sum(tempDataMV(rowMV{targetCol}(MVidx),NN).*WeightMultiplier);
        % Not weighted
        dataImputed(rowMV{targetCol}(MVidx),targetCol) = mean(tempDataMV(rowMV{targetCol}(MVidx),NN));
        writematrix(dataImputed,['M.csv'])
    end
end
end
```

I'm not sure if I'm maybe referring to the wrong thing or if I've put the `writematrix(dataImputed,['M.csv'])` in the wrong place.

I've also tried these sorts of routes:

```
% Convert cell to a table and use first row as variable names
T = cell2table(c(2:end,:),'VariableNames',c(1,:))
 
% Write the table to a CSV file
writetable(T,'myDataFile.csv')
```

```
dlmwrite(filename,M)
```

```
csvwrite('filename.csv',variable2,0,2)
```

[This is currently what my workspace looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjO3l.png)

Comment: "It doesn't show up" -- you might be looking in the wrong place. If these functions don't produce an error message, they should have produced a file. I suggest you use the full path when specifying the file name, that way it's unambiguous.

Comment: I've tried using the search function in file explorer ect to find it and nothing would show up.

Comment: @CrisLuengo how would I go about using the full path. Something like this?

`writematrix(dataImputed,['C:\\Users\\vicks\\OneDrive\\Uni\\Postgraduate\\Semester 3\\Data Science Project\\Cod\\M.csv'])`

Comment: That seems about right.

Comment: It still doesn't work. No errors but no files either.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `writematrix(dataImputed,'M.csv','WriteMode','append')`

If it's still not working, sharing the `AlzScSK.csv` with us would be helpful.